# C# Regular expression Example for Integrity

Tags: c#, expression

Can anyone tell me what this kind of Regular Expression is doing?

```
(\s*(\s*#\s*(?\d+)\s*))
```

If I test it an add whitespaces it says there is no match.

Can somebody give me an example? :)

Comment: use any online regex tool, you will have a full explanation on the right side https://regex101.com/r/xb7TTb/1 ,  https://regexr.com/5ov6o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Seems there was an error in the regular expression, which was then edited (not by OP) to a valid regex. I've reverted the edit, in case OP wonders why there are two different regexes now: original and [the edited one](https://regex101.com/r/xb7TTb/1)

Comment: Your regular expression is not correct. try this ```(\s*(\s*#\s*(\d+)\s*))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That regular expression is not correct. Try removing the ? character.

```
(\s*(\s*#\s*(\d+)\s*))
```

And this expression matches any number that has an # in front of it. For example, in the next lines, it matches lines 1,2,5 and 6.

```
  #995
#995
  995
995
#995 9
  #654 233
233
```

You can test it in the following link:
[http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cs*%28%5cs*%23%5cs*%28%5cd%2b%29%5cs*%29%29&i=++%23995%0d%0a%23995%0d%0a++995%0d%0a995%0d%0a%23995+9%0d%0a++%23654+233%0d%0a233](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cs*%28%5Cs*%23%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs*%29%29&i=%20%20%23995%0D%0A%23995%0D%0A%20%20995%0D%0A995%0D%0A%23995%209%0D%0A%20%20%23654%20233%0D%0A233)